# Looking for an elegant way to `time.sleep()` after every iteration, except the last iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a list of items: `list = [a, b, c, d]`
I'd like to modify each item and then `time.sleep(10)` before moving on to the next iteration. On the final iteration, I'd like to modify the item, but avoid sleeping.

```
for item in list:  
    # modify item  
    time.sleep(10) # avoid this line on the final iteration
```

Doesn't have to be this structure--looking for any method that gets the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another solution using `enumerate`:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for i, v in enumerate(lst, 1 - len(lst)):
    print(v)
    if i:
        print('sleeping')
```

**output**

```
a
sleeping
b
sleeping
c
sleeping
d
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're passing -3 as the starting index for enumerate, to iterate: -3, -2, -1, 0, and using 0 as False for the `if` statement?

Comment: @Simonsays Yes, that's correct. Zero is False-ish, and non-zero numbers are True-ish, in Python.

Answer (score 4):

You could sleep first, but skip sleep the first iteration sleep, instead:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(list):
    if idx != 0:   
        time.sleep(10) # avoid this line on the final iteration 
    # modify item
```

It falls off at the last item, without sleeping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` to track index :

```
for index, data in enumerate(list, 1 - len(list)):
    if index: 
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: **1** You can pass `enumerate` a starting value. **2** Why compute the list length on each loop iteration? It's not going to change (at least, I assume it's not going to change since it's generally not wise to change the length of a list that you're iterating over, unless you're very careful). Sure, getting the list length is a very fast operation, but still...

Comment: @PM2Ring Ahh, thanks for pointing out, I should use `enumerate(list, 1 - len(list))`

Comment: But this is exactly what you wrote @PM2Ring. By the way, thanks for mentioning out 2 points ( they are really helpful ) a learning for me

Answer (score 2):

If you inverse the problem and add a boolean to signal the first element you can do this:

```
do_sleep = False
for item in list:  
    if do_sleep:
        time.sleep(10) # avoid this line on the first iteration.
    else:
        do_sleep = True
    # modify item
```

Comment: Well spotted!Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid testing for the last element at each iteration.

```
for element in elements[:-1]:
    process_element(element)
    time.sleep(10)

process_element(element)
```

In case the changes needs to be applied to the elements within the list (without creating a new one).

```
for index, _ in enumerate(elements[:-1]):
    process_element(elements, index)
    time.sleep(10)

process_element(elements, -1)

def process_element(elements, index):
    elements[index] += 1
```

If you want to avoid copying the list you can use [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). Note that len([]) has O(1) cost.

```
for element in islice(elements, len(elements) - 1):
    ...

for index, _ in enumerate(islice(elements, len(elements) - 1)):
    ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't this altogether skip modifying the last item as well?

Comment: The [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) method can deal with the reference copy.

Comment: @Simonsays The last item is processed outside the loop.

Comment: Modifiying the answer to support @Simonsays use case.

Comment: Answer completed with both in place modification and iteration instead of slicing (copying).

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,item in enumerate(list):
    # modify item
    if i < len(list) - 1:
        time.sleep(10)
```